# How do I change icon with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have any AJAX call that allow to select an item, I'm displaying the selected item with a darker background and the icon marked selected.

I can change the background but when I attempt to change the icon doesn't work. Somebody can explain what I'm doing wrong?

Here it is the code

```
$("#accounts-list").on('click', '.nav-link', function () {
  var object_id = $(this).data('object-id');
  $.ajax({
    url: "url_to_ajax_call.php",
    data: {
      'account_id': object_id
    },
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (response) {
      // remove class where previously selected
      $(".nav-link").removeClass("bg-soft-primary"); // background
      $(".nav-link>span.fa-check-circle").removeClass("fa-check-circle").addClass("fa-circle"); // remove checked icon

      // apply selected class to the new item
      let item = $('.nav-link[data-object-id=' + object_id + ']');
      item.addClass('bg-soft-primary'); // apply background
      $(item + ">span.fa-circle").removeClass("fa-circle").addClass("fa-circle"); // select checked icon
    }
  })
})
```

```
    <div id="accounts-list">
      <ul class="nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <div class="nav-link nav-link-card-details bg-soft-primary"
               data-object-id="1">
            <span class="far fa-check-circle"></span>
            Item 1
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <div class="nav-link nav-link-card-details"
               data-object-id="2">
            <span class="far fa-circle"></span>
            Item 2
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <div class="nav-link nav-link-card-details"
               data-object-id="3">
            <span class="far fa-circle"></span>
            Item 3
          </div>
        </li><li class="nav-item">
        <div class="nav-link nav-link-card-details"
             data-object-id="4">

          <span class="far fa-circle"></span>
          Item 4
        </div>
        </li>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Thank you

Comment: Typo? `.removeClass("fa-circle").addClass("fa-circle")` should be `.removeClass("fa-circle").addClass("fa-check-circle")`

Comment: I frist need to remove the class from the current `nav-link` and substitute the icon with the `fa-circle`. I've tried like this but doesn't work: `$(".nav-link").find("span.fa-check-circle").removeClass("fa-check-circle").addClass("fa-circle");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `$(item + ">span.fa-circle")`, `item` is not a string to be used has a selector... It is a jQuery object.

So do it like this:

```
item.find("span.far")
```

Ho! To notice any effect, the should be two fontAwesome classes (one added and one different removed ;)

```
.removeClass("fa-check-circle").addClass("fa-circle")
```

Another way would be:

```
.toggleClass("fa-check-circle fa-circle")
```

Comment: it seems I can't select the `<span></span>` because the `.removeClass()`and `.addClass()` works perfectly for the background. `item.find("span.fa-circle").toggleClass("fa-check-circle fa-circle");`

Comment: mmm... That is because it depends on which icon is "loaded"... It will be best to use the `far` class then, because it does not change. I edited. ;)

Comment: Thanks for the input, I'm doing some debugging and if I run `alert(item.find("span").hasClass('far'));` I get back `false`

Comment: I've made a demo [here](https://jsbin.com/leletajora/edit?html,css,js,output). it works, I will try to replicate in production

Comment: I edited your bin [here](https://jsbin.com/biboruw/1/edit?html,css,js,output).

Comment: Thank you! it works! On my code there is a problem to find the right class but as soon as I fix it your solution worked out